# Loosing Session Connection on Link Click

Tags: session, oracle-apex

while working on an Oracle Apex Application, after implementing a custom login script where the user needs to register himself for the application before gaining access, [this Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMoVh.png) is thrown, after clicking the "Zugang beantragen"-Button which translates to requesting access.

Error translates to:
Your session has run out.
Close this Dialog and refresh the page to enter a new session.

If this issue could relate to my hardware then i will post the specs.
I already tried the login on various PCs and with different connections, restarted my pc, cleared the cache and cookies.

Any help answering this question is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems likely to be a session timeout which can be set at application, workspace and instance levels. Alternatively are you retaining the session id when redirecting into the application. It would help if you explained whether the 'custom login script' is implemented as part of the APEX application.

Comment: The custom scripts are run as part of a dynamic action upon pressing the Login Button. That part of the Login is working just fine.